# Shopping Cart: Sum on drop event (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopping-cart, droppable

I am currently creating a shopping cart with droppable and draggable element. Each element has a value (a price) and when dropped in the target that value is displayed in an input field. 
Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SamyAbouseda/jhchfwzg/

**HTML**

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" data-product="455">
<p>Product 1</p>
<p>455$</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content" data-product="37">
<p>Product 2</p>
<p>37$</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
<p>Shopping Cart</p>
</div>
<input id="sum" type="text"><span>$</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#draggable, #draggable2").draggable();
$("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.draggable.length);
    $('input').val(ui.draggable.data('product'));
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Product added to your cart!");
 }
});
```

Now, the goal is that when several element are dropped in the target the sum of those element should be displayed in the input field.

I found this [shopping cart](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/6/) which is almost the desired result, except that I need the dropped element to be displayed in the target (as per my current shopping cart). I tried to fiddle with it, add it to my code, started from scratch many time, but beside getting crazy about it I couldn't find a solution.

I am new in JQuery and not totally confortable with it yet. Any kind of help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Further your second fiddle shopping cart, I was made the needed changes. Of course that this code is not optimal but it does the job and let you a direction how to accomplish that.

The 2 changes I made is:

1. Hide the dropped item.
2. Show it when the user remove it from the shopping cart.

```js
var data = {"total":0,"rows":[]};
var totalCost = 0;


$(function(){
  $('#cartcontent').datagrid({
    singleSelect:true
  });
  $('.item').draggable({
    revert:true,
    //proxy:'clone',
    onStartDrag:function(){
      $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
      $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
    },
    onStopDrag:function(){
      $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
    }
  });
  $('.cart').droppable({
    onDragEnter:function(e,source){
      $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
    },
    onDragLeave:function(e,source){
      $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
    },
    onDrop:function(e,source){
      var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
      var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
      addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
      $(source).hide();
    }
  });
});

function addProduct(name,price){
  function add(){
    for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
      var row = data.rows[i];
      if (row.name == name){
        row.quantity += 1;
        return;
      }
    }
    data.total += 1;
    data.rows.push({
      name:name,
      quantity:1,
      price:price,
      remove: '<a href="#" class="remove" onclick="removeProduct(this, event)">X</a>'
    });
  }
  add();
  totalCost += price;
  $('#cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data);
  $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $'+totalCost);
}

function removeProduct(el, event) {
  var tr = $(el).closest('tr');
  var name = tr.find('td[field=name]').text();
  var price = tr.find('td[field=price]').text();
  var quantity = tr.find('td[field=quantity]').text();
  for(var i = 0; i < data.total; i++){
    var row = data.rows[i];
    if (row.name == name) {
      data.rows.splice(i, 1);
      data.total--;
      break;
    }
  }
  totalCost -=  price * quantity;
  $('#cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data);
  $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $'+totalCost);
  var li = $('p:contains(' + name + ')').parents('.item').first().show();
  console.log(name, li);
}
```

```css
.products{
  list-style:none;
  margin-right:300px;
  padding:0px;
  height:100%;
}
.products li{
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
.item{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.item img{
  border:1px solid #333;
}
.item p{
  margin:0;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  color:#c3c3c3;
}
.cart{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
  background:#ccc;
  padding:0px 10px;
}
h1{
  text-align:center;
  color:#555;
}
h2{
  position:absolute;
  font-size:16px;
  left:10px;
  bottom:20px;
  color:#555;
}
.total{
  margin:0;
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="products">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="item">
      <img src="images/shirt1.gif"/>
      <div>
        <p>Balloon</p>
        <p>Price:$25</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="item">
      <img src="images/shirt2.gif"/>
      <div>
        <p>Feeling</p>
        <p>Price:$25</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="item">
      <img src="images/shirt3.gif"/>
      <div>
        <p>Elephant</p>
        <p>Price:$25</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="item">
      <img src="images/shirt4.gif"/>
      <div>
        <p>Stamps</p>
        <p>Price:$25</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="item">
      <img src="images/shirt5.gif"/>
      <div>
        <p>Monogram</p>
        <p>Price:$25</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="item">
      <img src="images/shirt6.gif"/>
      <div>
        <p>Rolling</p>
        <p>Price:$25</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="cart">
  <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
  <div style="background:#fff">
    <table id="cartcontent" fitColumns="true" style="width:300px;height:auto;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
          <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
          <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
          <th field="remove" width=60 align="right">Remove</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p class="total">Total: $0</p>
  <h2>Drop here to add to cart</h2>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/143/